# How to split result data while getting from ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, logic

This is my JS BLOCK for making ajax call --

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myid').change(function () {
        var optval = $('#myid').val();

        if (optval == 3) {
            var url = '<?php echo base_url ?>datapage.php';
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                success: function (results) {
                    $('#datadiv').html(results);
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

How can i split the data from the results as i already tried something like this but its not working  `results.serialize()` . Although commenting the blocks in `datapage.php`  is a way but i dont want to do it in that way

PS--

> results is a full page with tr and td in it, i just want to fetch the
>   data...actually datapage.php is in use with other files too so cant
>   modify it more and creating new page to fetch data is also not
>   provided :( ...one more thing i m trying to pass data and on that page
>   im using `$get['data'] == mystring` then FETCH MY DESIRE RESULT
>   otherwise DO THE SAME..is this ok or any other method??

Thi sis what im getting in my results -- http://pastebin.com/ky9Lzuuu

Comment: Do you mean that `results` is a full web page and you only want to use an html fragment that is contained in `results`?

Comment: What is `results` like and how do you want to split it ?

Comment: What is your data format? XML, JSON, ???

Comment: u can show me result output and how u need?

Comment: results is a full page with tr and td in it, i just want to fetch the data...actually datapage.php is in use with other files too so cant modify it more and creating new page to fetch data is also not provided :( ...one more thing i m trying to pass data and on that page im using $get['data'] == mystring then FETCH MY DESIRE RESULT otherwise DO THE SAME..is this ok or any other method??

Comment: what do you mean by split? you might be looking for $(results).filter('#iwanthisDiv') ??

Comment: can you show what value should the "results" have?

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've [beautified](http://jsbeautifier.org/) your JS code (because the way you had it with no indenting was too hard to read).

Comment: Results --- http://pastebin.com/ky9Lzuuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have an HTML being returned from server you can simply use jQuery selector to get the required part of HTML and insert it into the page

In case it is a particular tr with id "myTR" then do this:

```
$('#datadiv').html($(results).find("tr#myTR").html());
```